# npm node-gyp (node-sass) requirements for windows

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install, node-gyp, node-sass

a week ago i had to install python and Visual C++ Compiler (Windows Build Tools) in order to get my angular project running.

(See README https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp)

Since a few days this requirements are not needed anymore. I can run **npm install** on my project and all packages are installed perfectly.

Does anybode have an idea what changed? I really need to know why this is working right now without python and windows build tools.

Answer (score 0):

node-sass provides prebuilt binaries for supported platforms. I'm guessing you installed Node 8 before binaries were available for the release. When the install can't find our prebuilt binaries, it requires the node-gyp setup to build them on your machine.

Comment: Thanks, but no. Node 6.x is installed and i have to set a SASS_BINARY_PATH for a local package download instead getting it over internet from github. The reason is a restricted network. So i have to build it on my machine.